# Apache POI (Java) : Display embedded files on Microsoft Word (.docx)

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, openxml, docx

It's my first time posting here :)

I want with apache POI to embed a file inside a .docx and reference it via an icon or a link inside the document.

I guess I've managed to embed the file.
My problem : I can't display a reference to the embed file.

To illustrate my problem:
With the following code, I've manage to embed inside myWord.docx the file "first.txt" at the location "/word/embeddings/first.txt".
I don't know how to reference it.

This is my code :

```
public void saveToDocx(OutputStream myOutputStream){

    Resource r = new ClassPathResource("/myWord.docx") ; 
    try (FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(r.getFile())){
        OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(fis);
        XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(pkg);
        fis.close();

        // first.txt
        final PackagePartName partName = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName("/word/embeddings/first.txt");
        final PackagePart pkgPart = pkg.createPart(partName, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.oleobject");
        final OutputStream partOutputStream = pkgPart.getOutputStream();
        partOutputStream.write("test test test".getBytes());    
        partOutputStream.close();
        pkgPart.addRelationship(partName, TargetMode.INTERNAL, "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/oleObject");

        //image.jpg
        String imageName = "C:/image.jpg";
        InputStream imageIS = new FileInputStream(imageName);
        imageIS.close();
        imgPartOutputStream.close();

        //add simple picture to my document
        XWPFParagraph myParagraph = docx.createParagraph(); 
        XWPFRun run = myParagraph.createRun();
        run.addPicture(imageIS,  XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, imageName, Units.toEMU(77.25), Units.toEMU(49.5));

        docx.write(myOutputStream);
        //pkg.save(myOutputStream); there is a difference between this and docx.write ?

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Can someone please try to help me? I'm really stuck (since last Friday). Thanks guys!
(Do forgive me for my grammar, i'm not a native :/)

Comment: For what its worth, you can do OLE embedding with the commercial Docx4j Enterprise edition.

Comment: It seems nobody has a complete answer here, therefore I would probably create a simple such document and unzip the .docx file (it's actually a .zip) and then take a look which things are set in the various files to see how it is done by Word itself. A bit of tedious work but might solve it for you...

Comment: @centic thank you for you answers, I already done this work and I know how it is done by Word. When I embed file using word, ms-word added code into document.xml .

So I want to insert this code using ApachePOI, changing the id of the embed object  by the id of my embed file already created

Comment: @H.Yet if you have solved this problem, can you please paste the complete example. I am having same problem.